# Handling COALESCE in dynamic SQL with CONVERT

Tags: sql, t-sql, stored-procedures, dynamic-sql

There is this a stored procedure that joins table to retrieve the required results. It needs to filter it by a @cha_id, and where it is not provided by the user, it will take whatever is in tablea accordingly. How do we handle COALESCE in a dynamic SQL query? I couldn't get it as CONVERT should also be undergoing for @cha_id. For example, if the COALESCE or ISNULL wasn't required, this would work

```
WHERE tablea.chan_id = '''+CONVERT(VARCHAR,@chan_id)+'''
```

would work. But I couldn't figure it out in the case I require the COALESCE/ISNULL.

```
WHERE tablea.chan_id = COALESCE(CONVERT(VARCHAR,@chan_id),tablea.chan_id)
```

I've been researching in vain. Any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

try like below

```
  'SELECT * FROM tablea WHERE tablea.changelogtype_id= COALESCE(' + @cha_id + ', tablea.chan_id)'
```

Comment: Thank you! This would work under normal script. But I need it in a dynamic SQL.